# custom camera zoom Functionality IPhone Take Photo

Tags: iphone, camera, photo, take

I am successfully able to Make custom Zoom using Slider in my Custom Camera view using following code

```
imagePickerController.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(initialTransform, MainSlider.value, MainSlider.value);
```

Screen Looks Zoom as it should be ... 
But when i call Take Picture function

```
[self.imagePickerController takePicture];
```

and tryng to access Photo in method :

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {



UIImage *Originalimage = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];


UIImage *Editimage = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];


}
```

Here I receive Original Image without Zoom n "Originalimage" but i dont get anything in "Editimage"

I am trying to get Image with Zoom that i get using cameraViewTransform!!

I hope its more clear now ... .

Thank you

Comment: IS there any one to help me out ... I tried lot but didnt get any success !!

Comment: It's really hard to tell what you are trying to do here. At the risk of sounding like an asshole, I propose that you'd get more help if you made your question a little easier to understand (this includes errant capitalization, punctuation, code-formatting, English syntax, etc.).

Comment: Thank you for such a good suggestions ! I will make it clear ,,,, for you 1!!

Comment: You should really ask a question. What is your problem, and what do you expect?

Comment: I thought its clear ... I am creating custom zoom and taking photos using button click ...    And once i zoom, i want to get Zoomed Image !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok .. I got indirect way to get the zoomed image ....

Once i zoom image and take picture , I take the Originial picture and zoom that Image upto that scale ... and than use of this function 
"UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext" for selected bound ...

And i get that zoomed image ...

Still i dont know why i dont get anything in UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage , May be i am editing nothing... just scaling it ... may be thats why its not giving me anythiing in Edited Image ...

Thank you for your help and support !!

Comment: Above said process do apply zoom to image but it apply zoom to top left corner & not to exact where zoom is applied